# Collapsible sidebar using bslib without additional JS?

Tags: r, shiny, version, sidebar, bslib

I'm looking to shift from `{shinydashboard}` and `{bs4Dash}` towards `{bslib}` while keeping the nice feature of having a global collapsible sidebar in my apps.

In this [`{bslib}` vignette](https://rstudio.github.io/bslib/articles/sidebars.html) some functions such as `layout_sidebar()` or `page_navbar()` are used as examples but I cannot find the first function in my latest version of `{bslib}` (`0.4.2`) nor can I find the `sidebar` argument in the `page_navbar()` function (same for `sidebar()` function).

There must be a simple explanation, but I can't figure why. Is the vignette outdated and these functions have been dropped ?

I tried installing directly from the github repo ([rstudio/bslib](https://github.com/rstudio/bslib)), but the issue is the same.

More generally, is this possible to use exclusively `{shiny}` and `{bslib}` without additional Javascript to leverage a collapsible global sidebar as it could be done in `{bs4Dash}` using `bs4Dash::dashboardSidebar()` ?

I love the possibilities offered by `{bslib}` (fine tuning with bootstrap 5 and `bs_add_variables()`) and would appreciate a clean solution for sidebars. If this doesn't exist, does anyone knows when it will be available ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the development version of **bslib**:

```r
remotes::install_github("rstudio/bslib")
```

Then an example is:

```r
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- page_navbar(
  nav(
    "Plot",
    plotOutput("gg")
  ),
  sidebar = sidebar(
    numericInput("test", "Test", value = 5)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output[["gg"]] <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(
      iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)
    ) + geom_point()    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I'm clueless as to why my github installation attempt did not work, but now it works. Thanks !

Comment: @MichaëlWeber I'm glad it didn't work. you question really helped with my issue